# How does StatsD store its data?

Tags: statsd

I've been going through the README at https://github.com/etsy/statsd but I can't figure out how does StatsD store the data it gets?

Does it do any permanent storage or is it one off thing? I was trying to figure out what database (if any) it uses or if it simply uses a file-based storage.

Answer (score 7):

Etsy's version of statsD does not store data per se but relies on "backends" to do something with the data it aggregates (e.g. print them out, send them to another statsD server or send them to graphite) as shown in https://github.com/etsy/statsd/tree/master/backends.

If you want permanent storage, you'll need to stand up a [graphite server](http://graphite.wikidot.com/), use a [hosted one](http://www.hostedgraphite.com/) or use a service that supports statsD natively (e.g. [Datadog](http://www.datadoghq.com)).

Disclosure: I work for [Datadog](http://www.datadoghq.com).