# How do I retrieve data from statsd?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, statsd

I'm glossing over their documentation here :

http://www.rubydoc.info/github/github/statsd-ruby/Statsd

And there's methods for recording data, but I can't seem to find anything about retrieving recorded data. I'm adopting a projecting with an existing statsd addition. It's host is likely a defunct URL. Perhaps, is the host where those stats are recorded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 parts to statsd: a client and a server.
What you're looking at is the client part. You will not see functionality related to retrieving the data as it's not there - it normally is on the server side.

Here is a list of statsd server implementations:
http://www.joemiller.me/2011/09/21/list-of-statsd-server-implementations/
Research and pick one that fits your needs.

Statsd originally started at etsy: https://github.com/etsy/statsd/wiki

Answer (score 2):

The statsd server implementations that Mircea links just take care of receiving, aggregating metrics and publishing them to a backend service. [Etsy's statsd](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/README.md#statsd-) definition (bold is mine):

> A network daemon that runs on the Node.js platform and listens for
>   statistics, like counters and timers, sent over UDP or TCP and **sends
>   aggregates to one or more pluggable backend services (e.g.,
>   Graphite)**.

To retrieve the recorded data you have to query the backend. Check [the list of available backends](https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/docs/backend.md). The most common one is Graphite.

See also this question: [How does StatsD store its data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502149/how-does-statsd-store-its-data)